# Delete / remove data from Firebase Android & Web

Tags: java, android, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I have a quick question, I have searched online but I can't find any useful information.

Is it possible to clear / delete firebase data from Android app and web app without the app being open. For example, I have developed a application and I want the data which is retrieved from Firebase to be deleted at 6:45 every day but the app will not be running at this time.

Currently, I can do something like:

```
myData.parent().setValue(null);
```

OR

```
myData.getRef().removeValue();
```

However, if the app is not running then the data does not get deleted.

Comment: Firebase also has a server SDK. It is called Admin,  The server SDKs are for node js and java. You can run your script on the server and update it whenever you want

Comment: You can have a look at the [Admin Server Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: Do I need to have my own server or does Firebase provide them?

Comment: You will need you own, but there are free options for platform-as-a-service if you're just getting started with low resource usage. Heroku or Google App Engine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

...until now!

Firebase has just rolled out [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/features/functions/), a hosted Node.js runtime for things such as this. You can write code to be executed in response to events in the database, file storage, etc. - including [periodic maintenance with cron jobs.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

Comment: Would this work, even if the app/web app is not running?

Comment: Functions are independent of any other client connection. Think of it as an always-on observer, which can perform actions based on its own criteria.

Comment: Oh, great. I understand now. I was thinking it differently. Can I also check if this can be used for mobile apps as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Have you read through the developers guide? It's a persistent server-side environment running JavaScript code that integrates with the rest of your Firebase project through event listeners or "triggers". It can be "used for" whatever you can come up with given that architecture, eg. [these use cases.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases)